# Docker User-defined network is not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have created a bridged docker network using,

> docker network create --driver bridge exa1

but when I use this network in my docker-compose and run it,

it results with this output,

> ERROR: plugin "exa1" not found

I have made sure the exa1 network exists using docker network ls

and does it really exist?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please include your compose file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you got a syntax error in your docker-compose.yml.

Here is my docker-compose file. Take notice on the external: true option.

```
version: "3"
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    container_name: traefik
    command:
      - --api
      - --docker
      - --docker.exposedbydefault=false
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - exa1
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
networks:
  exa1:
    external: true
```

Comment: Glad it helps you :D